# JRadioButtonMenuItem as not a JRadioButton extend

Tags: java, swing

Look at image below and notice `JRadioButtonMenuItem` do not extends `JRadioButton`, even not `JToggleButton`. My guess is that they repeat code. `:P` Or perhaps they have a intermediary class inside these toggle component?

[image]

Comment: you may want to download the source and look up each difference

Comment: Please cite/credit the image source.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to know whether you're right about the two classes sharing code? Do you want to know what the similarities and differences between the two classes are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that Java does not support multiple inheritance, otherwise you could have considered having `JRadioButtonMenuItem` extending both `JMenuItem` and `JRadioButton` (although it is not clear if it would have been a good implementation choice).

So this means that you have to choose one or the other, in this case, the choice has been made to extend `JMenuItem`.

Now, if you take a look, you see that `JMenuItem` and `JRadioButton` have a common ancestor which is `AbstractButton` which actually encapsulates a `ButtonModel` where everything related to the current state of a button is stored (armed, selected, etc...).

In the case of a `JRadioButtonMenuItem` it uses a `ToggleButtonModel` and so here you have how the same model is shared by `JRadioButton` and `JRadioButtonMenutItem`.

Regarding the view, this is all delegated into the `BasicRadioButtonMenuItemUI` and especially more into `BasicMenuItemUI` (which is the parent of `BasicRadioButtonMenuItemUI`). Eventually it relies on the current Look-and-feel to provide the different icons, styles, borders, fonts, etc...

And this is how the whole thing goes.

Comment: +1 for citing the UI delegate. It's more work for the delegate, but also more flexibility.